# Binary Search Trees Switching subtrees

Tags: c

So I'm trying to write a function that when given two pointers to nodes in the BST, will 'switch' the subtree locations.

```
typedef struct NODE { 
  struct NODE* parent;
  struct NODE* left;
  struct NODE* right;
}node_t;
```

This is the node struct I have for the BST.

My function goes along the line of :

```
void switch_subtree(node_t* a, node_t* b)
{
  if (a==NULL || b==NULL)
    {
      return;
    }

  if (a->parent->left == a)
  {
    a->parent->left = b;
  }
  else
  {
    a->parent->right = b;
  }

  if (b->parent->left == b)
  {
    b->parent->left = a;
  }
  else
  {
    b->parent->right = a;
  }

  nodes * temp = a;
  a->parent = b->parent;
  b->parent = temp->parent;
}
```

However, when I run it, it does not properly switch the subtrees.

Can anyone point out any errors Im making and point me in the right direction?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
nodes * temp = a;
  a->parent = b->parent;
  b->parent = temp->parent;
```

correctly it should read:

```
nodes * temp = a->parent;
  a->parent = b->parent;
  b->parent = temp;
```

otherwise `a->parent` is forever lost after line 2.

### rationale

#### wrong approach

The line `temp = a` will make both pointers `temp` and `a` point to the same NODE structure:

```
                   +- > +--------+      +- > +--------+
                   |    |        |      |    |        |     
                   |    | ...    |      |    | ...    |     
                   |    +--------+      |    +--------+
                   |                    |
                   +--------------+     +----------------+
                                  |                      |
         +--------+- > +--------+ |     +- > +---------+ |
         |        |    | parent |-+     |    | parent  |-+
         |        |    | ...    |       |    | ...     |
         |        |    +--------+       |    +---------+
         |        |                     |
+------+ |  +---+ |               +---+ |               
| temp |-+  | a |-+               | b |-+               
+------+    +---+                 +---+
```

Changing `a->parent` in line 2 (`a->parent = b->parent`) will also change `temp->parent` as both are just different names for the same component (`parent`) of the same NODE structure:

```
                       +--------+   +---+- > +--------+
                       |        |   |   |    |        |     
                       | ...    |   |   |    | ...    |     
                       +--------+   |   |    +--------+
                                    |   |
                                    |   +--------------+
                                    |                   |
         +--------+- > +--------+   |   +- > +---------+
         |        |    | parent |---+   |    | parent  |
         |        |    | ...    |       |    | ...     |
         |        |    +--------+       |    +---------+
         |        |                     |
+------+ |  +---+ |               +---+ |               
| temp |-+  | a |-+               | b |-+               
+------+    +---+                 +---+
```

The assignment `b->parent = temp->parent` doesn't change anything at all, as both `b->parent` and `temp->parent` are already pointing at the same node.
**- mistake !**

#### alternative

Taking a look at the proposed alternative, `temp = a->parent` will leave you with the situation sketched below:

```
         +---------+- > +--------+      +- > +--------+
         |         |    |        |      |    |        |     
         |         |    | ...    |      |    | ...    |     
         |         |    +--------+      |    +--------+
         |         |                    |
         |         +--------------+     +----------------+
         |                        |                      |
         |        +- > +--------+ |     +- > +---------+ |
         |        |    | parent |-+     |    | parent  |-+
         |        |    | ...    |       |    | ...     |
         |        |    +--------+       |    +---------+
         |        |                     |
+------+ |  +---+ |               +---+ |               
| temp |-+  | a |-+               | b |-+               
+------+    +---+                 +---+
```

After `a->parent = b->parent` `temp` is still pointing to the original parent node of the node pointed to by `a`:

```
         +----------- > +--------+      +- > +--------+
         |              |        |      |    |        |     
         |              | ...    |      |    | ...    |     
         |              +--------+      |    +--------+
         |                              |
         |                        +-----+----------------+
         |                        |                      |
         |        +- > +--------+ |     +- > +---------+ |
         |        |    | parent |-+     |    | parent  |-+
         |        |    | ...    |       |    | ...     |
         |        |    +--------+       |    +---------+
         |        |                     |
+------+ |  +---+ |               +---+ |               
| temp |-+  | a |-+               | b |-+               
+------+    +---+                 +---+
```

Finally assigning `b->parent = temp` will give the node pointed to by `b` the right parent:

```
         +--------+-- > +--------+  +----- > +--------+
         |        |     |        |  |        |        |     
         |        |     | ...    |  |        | ...    |     
         |        |     +--------+  |        +--------+
         |        |                 |
         |        +-----------------|--------------------+
         |                          |                    |
         |        +- > +--------+   |   +- > +---------+ |
         |        |    | parent |---+   |    | parent  |-+
         |        |    | ...    |       |    | ...     |
         |        |    +--------+       |    +---------+
         |        |                     |
+------+ |  +---+ |               +---+ |               
| temp |-+  | a |-+               | b |-+               
+------+    +---+                 +---+
```

Comment: Is this because nodes * temp is just a pointer pointing to one specific location? Thereby doing nodes * temp = a->parent allows temp to directly point to a->parent?

Comment: yes, maybe I should have made it more clear in the answer. I will try to fix this.